# Blocbuilder is not being called after manipulating the list inside the state

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

Blocbuilder is not being called after the list inside the state is changed or item added or removed.
BlocBuilder is not used with buildwhen,

bloc state manipulation code is as below

```
FutureOr<void> _removeFilter(OnFilterRemoved event,
      Emitter<SearchState> emit,) {
    if (state.selectedFilters != null && state.selectedFilters!.isNotEmpty) {
      state.selectedFilters!.remove(event.text);
      if (event.text == state.selectedAvailability) {
        state.selectedAvailability = '';
      } else {
        state.medicineList.map((element) {
          if (element.name == event.text) {
              element.checked = false;
              return;
          }
        });
      }
    }
    emit(
      state,
    );
  }
```

and bloc builder is as below

```
return BlocBuilder<SearchBloc, SearchState>(
      bloc: BlocProvider.of<SearchBloc>(context),
      builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
        List? selectedFilter = state.selectedFilters;
        if (selectedFilter != null && selectedFilter.isNotEmpty) {
          return Container(
            height: 4.h,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.h, bottom: 1.h),
            child: ListView.builder(
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code implies that `SearchState` is mutable. To avoid such unexpected problems, always make sure that your state classes are immutable. One of the possible approaches is to use [`freezed`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).

This way, you make some changes to your current state by using `copyWith` and `emit()` the returned object.